# How can I get these classes to inherit these traits?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

My problem stipulates the following, dealing with birds:

1. Birds can fly.
2. Ducks fly but also swim.
3. Penguins do not fly.
4. Penguins deep dive, unlike ducks.
5. Only parrots can talk.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Code
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Bird[] birds = new Bird[3]; 
    birds[0] = new Duck(true, false, false, false); 
    birds[1] = new Penguin(false, true, false, true); 
    birds[2] = new Parrot(true, false, true, false); 
  }
}

abstract class Bird 
{ 
  abstract boolean flight();
  abstract boolean deepdive();
  abstract boolean talk();
  abstract boolean swim();

  Bird (boolean flight, boolean deepdive, boolean talk, boolean swim)
  {
    this.flight = flight;
    this.deepdive = deepdive;
    this.talk = talk;
    this.swim = swim;
  }

}

abstract class Duck extends Bird
{
  public Duck(boolean flight, boolean deepdive, boolean talk, boolean swim)
  {
    super(flight, deepdive, talk, swim);
  }
  abstract public boolean flight();
  abstract public boolean deepdive();
  abstract public boolean talk();
  abstract public boolean swim();
}

abstract class Penguin extends Bird
{
  public Penguin(boolean flight, boolean deepdive, boolean talk, boolean swim)
  {
    super(flight, deepdive, talk, swim);
  }
  abstract public boolean flight();
  abstract public boolean deepdive();
  abstract public boolean talk();
  abstract public boolean swim();
}

abstract class Parrot extends Bird
{
  public Parrot(boolean flight, boolean deepdive, boolean talk, boolean swim)
  {
    super(flight, deepdive, talk, swim);
  } 
  abstract public boolean flight();
  abstract public boolean deepdive();
  abstract public boolean talk();
  abstract public boolean swim();
}
```

My idea was to have each activity as a true or false field, and then output from each animal saying what he can and cannot do, via a loop. However, whenever I try to get it to run, it gives me: "Void methods cannot return a value" and "This method requires a body instead of a semicolon." How can I get this to work?

EDIT: I've implemented some of what people said to do below, but I still get "cannot instantiate the type ..." and "...cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: If `Penguin` does not fly, don't allow its constructor to be called with `flight == true`: simply pass `true` to the `super` constructor (etc for other properties, and other subclasses).

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with inheritance; you're simply trying to return a `Bird` from your `void main` method. Either replace the return with `return;` (no value) or... do *something else*, which isn't clear what that would be, since it's not clear why you'd want to return a `Bird`.

Comment: I had 'new Penguin(false, true, false, true); ' with the order being flight, deepdive, talk, swim, so I thought it was false. Also, which super constructor should I pass stuff to? Which is the super constructor vs non-super ones?

Comment: `for (Bird b : birds) return  b;` What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to put out a serious of trues and falses for each type of bird, so I can write a loop so they say quotes about what they do.

Answer (score 2):

Lets focus in the model first.

The best way to represent this model in java is with concrete separated classes and interfaces.

```
class Bird implements Flyer
class Duck implements Flyer, Swimmer
class Penguin implements Swimmer, DeepDiver
class Parrot implements Flyer, Talker
```

Observe that Liskov Substitution Principle does not allow to remove behaviour from a superclass in a subclass. That is why you can not say that `Bird` *`is a`* `Flyer`, `Penguin` *`is a`* `Bird` but `Penguin` *`is not a`* `Flyer`. In other words other `Bird` users would expect the `Flyer` behaviour and that expectation would fail for `Penguin`, in this case inheritance is not the correct approach.

Now talking about implementation.

Java has no multiple inheritance or mix-in but in java 8 you can have a default method implementation in interfaces.

Hint: avoid using `instanceof`, use polymorphism instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** The compiler says that "`void` methods cannot return a value" is because you are returning the first `Bird` instance in your `birds` array in your `main` method, which is declared `void`.

To fix this, simply remove the `for` loop in your `main` method.

**Problem 2:** The compiler says that "This method requires a body instead of a semicolon" because methods without a body in an `abstract` class need to be declared `abstract`, like so:
   `abstract boolean flight();`

To fix this, declare all the methods without a body in your `Bird` class `abstract`.

**Problem 3:**  The compiler says that "you cannot instantiate the type" because the type you are trying to instantiate is an `abstract` class. The root of this problem is that `Duck`, `Penguin`, and `Parrot` are `abstract` classes when they don't need to be. The child classes of `Bird` should *override* the methods in the `Bird` class, that is why you declared the methods in the `Bird` class `abstract`.

To fix this, remove the `abstract` modifier on all of the methods in the `Duck`, `Penguin`, and `Parrot` classes and add a body to those methods. It is also conventional to add the `@Override` annotation on the line before any overridden method.

**Problem 4:** The compiler says that "XXX cannot be resolved or is not a field" means that you have not declared the fields `flight`, `deepdive`, `talk`, and `swim`.

To fix this, declare those fields in the `Bird` class (Example: `private boolean XXX;`).

However, this will give you an unused warning because in the code these fields will only have values and those values will never be used. To fix this you can remove the fields and the references to them entirely, make getters and setters for them, or any other method that would use them, or add `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` the line before the `Bird` class declaration (*Not recommended*).

**Further reading:**

- [Abstract Methods and Classes - The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)
- [Inheritance - The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

<sup><sub>**Note:** This should only be a temporary solution, as the answer @JonasFagundes suggested is simply a better way to tackle this problem as a whole.</sub></sup>

Comment: I made those changes; I'm still getting "flight cannot be resolved or is not a field" & "This method requires a body instead of a semicolon"

Comment: 7, 8, 9, 22, 23, 24, 25

Comment: what do you mean "add a body to those methods? What should be in that body?

Comment: The body is the code between the opening and closing curly braces (`{` and `}`). The method should return a `boolean` representing if that `Bird` type can do that action. Example: In class `Penguin`, `flight()` would return `false` and `deepDive()` would return `true`.